TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'propertyType')
I have mongoose question..
// Match location pattern against database fields
    let query = {
        $or: [
            { name: locationPattern },
            { 'details.description': locationPattern },
            { 'location.address': locationPattern },
        ],
    }

    // Only check for property if its not 'All'
    if (propertyType && propertyType !== 'All') {
        const typePattern = new RegExp(propertyType, 'i')
        query.details.propertyType = typePattern
    }

Bu i have issue on this line when tryin to add another criteria on my questy.
query.details.propertyType = typePattern

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'propertyType')
What the issue and what is the proper syntax?
Proper syntax to add a criteria on my query

This is a message that can appear in all programming languages, and is fairly simple to debug. The message is telling you that in the reference query.details.propertyType one of those parts is invalid, so it cannot get the information you are asking for. You will need to use your debugger to find out which part, and why it has not been initialised with a valid reference. I do not know mongoose but in the let statement above, there is no mention of details.propertyType; perhaps that needs to be checked.

Thank you! found the issue.
query['details.propertyType'] = typePattern
